# Mapbox: How to get address string from LatLng?

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, mapbox-android

Using Mapbox Maps SDK for Android 8.2.1, how can I get an address using a `LatLng` object?

I tried following the [Mapbox reverse geocoding documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding), but I don't know how to get the result and convert it to a string. I can see that `result` is a `CarmenFeature` list, but I don't know how to work with that.

How can I accomplish this? My attempt is below uses the point `pointFromLatLng` and the string I'd like the address to be store at, `chosenLocationString`. Thanks!

```java
if(chosenLatLng != null) {

    MapboxGeocoding mapboxGeocoding = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
            .accessToken("my access token")
            .query(pointFromLatLng)
            .build();

    mapboxGeocoding.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {

            List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();

            chosenLocationString = results.;

            if (results.size() > 0) {

                // Log the first results Point.
                Point firstResultPoint = results.get(0).center();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + firstResultPoint.toString());

            } else {

                // No result for your request were found.
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: No result found");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });



    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("location", chosenLocationString);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    SetEventLocationActivity.this.finish();

}
```

---

**Update:**
Here is my current implementation that gives a null `feature.address()`. `makeGeocodeSearch(chosenLatLng)` is called in onCreate.

*onCreate():*

```java
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_event_location);

        set_location_button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.set_location_button);

        // When Set Location button is clicked, set street address textview, close activity
        set_location_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chosenLatLng != null) {

                    // Geocoding called here
                    makeGeocodeSearch(chosenLatLng);

                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("location", chosenLocationString);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

                    SetEventLocationActivity.this.finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Tap the search button to enter the event location",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

*onActivityResult():*

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {

            // Retrieve selected location's CarmenFeature
            CarmenFeature selectedCarmenFeature = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(data);

            // Create a new FeatureCollection and add a new Feature to it using selectedCarmenFeature above.
            // Then retrieve and update the source designated for showing a selected location's symbol layer icon

            if (mapboxMap != null) {
                Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();
                if (style != null) {
                    GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(geojsonSourceLayerId);
                    if (source != null) {
                        source.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(
                                new Feature[] {Feature.fromJson(selectedCarmenFeature.toJson())}));
                    }

                    chosenLatLng = new LatLng(((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).latitude(),
                            ((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).longitude());

                    // Move map camera to the selected location
                    mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                            new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(new LatLng(((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).latitude(),
                                            ((Point) selectedCarmenFeature.geometry()).longitude()))
                                    .zoom(14)
                                    .build()), 4000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*makeGeocodeSearch():*

```java
private void makeGeocodeSearch(LatLng latLng) {
        try {
            // Build a Mapbox geocoding request
            MapboxGeocoding client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                    .accessToken(<ACCESS_TOKEN>)
                    .query(Point.fromLngLat(latLng.getLongitude(), latLng.getLatitude()))
                    .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_PLACE)
                    .build();

            client.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call,
                                       Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
                        if (results.size() > 0) {

                            // Get the first Feature from the successful geocoding response
                            CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

                            // Get the address string from the CarmenFeature
                            chosenLocationString = feature.address();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SetEventLocationActivity.this,
                                    "No results in Geocoding request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("TAG","Geocoding Failure: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
            Log.e("TAG","Error geocoding: " + servicesException.toString());
            servicesException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

**Update 2:** I updated `makeGeocodeSearch()` to call the intent inside there instead, however I'm still having the same issue.

```java
private void makeGeocodeSearch(LatLng latLng) {
        try {
            // Build a Mapbox geocoding request
            MapboxGeocoding client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
                    .accessToken(<ACCESS_TOKEN>)
                    .query(Point.fromLngLat(latLng.getLongitude(), latLng.getLatitude()))
                    .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_PLACE)
                    .build();

            client.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call,
                                       Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
                        if (results.size() > 0) {

                            // Get the first Feature from the successful geocoding response
                            CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

                            // Get the address string from the CarmenFeature
                            chosenLocationString = feature.address();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SetEventLocationActivity.this,
                                    "No results in Geocoding request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    // Return intent with chosenLocationString, finish this activity
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("location", chosenLocationString);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    SetEventLocationActivity.this.finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("TAG","Geocoding Failure: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
            Log.e("TAG","Error geocoding: " + servicesException.toString());
            servicesException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
private void makeGeocodeSearch(final LatLng latLng) {
    try {
      // Build a Mapbox geocoding request
      MapboxGeocoding client = MapboxGeocoding.builder()
        .accessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .query(Point.fromLngLat(latLng.getLongitude(), latLng.getLatitude()))
        .geocodingTypes(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_PLACE)
        .build();
      client.enqueueCall(new Callback<GeocodingResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GeocodingResponse> call,
                               Response<GeocodingResponse> response) {
          if (response.body() != null) {
            List<CarmenFeature> results = response.body().features();
            if (results.size() > 0) {

              // Get the first Feature from the successful geocoding response
              CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

              // Get the address string from the CarmenFeature
              String carmenFeatureAddress = feature.address();



            } else {
              Toast.makeText(GeocodingActivity.this, "no results in geocoding request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GeocodingResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
          Log.e(TAG,"Geocoding Failure: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
      });
    } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
      Logd.e(TAG,"Error geocoding: " + servicesException.toString());
      servicesException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The more specific answer to your question is the following part of the code above:

```
// Get the first Feature from the successful geocoding response
              CarmenFeature feature = results.get(0);

              // Get the address string from the CarmenFeature
              String carmenFeatureAddress = feature.address();
```

`feature.address();` is a String, so you don't need to do any more conversion after `address()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I never thought I'd get an answer!

However, `carmenFeatureAddress` ends up `null` for some reason. I didn't change anything from your code.

Comment: Allow me to specify, `feature.address()` is `null`. Most other fields of `feature` are not null, though.

Comment: Yes, `address()` can return null. From the javadocs for the `CarmenFeature`'s `address()`:
"@return while the string content isn't guaranteed, and might return null, in many cases, this will be the house number"

Can you share your actual geocoding query url? 
`call.request().url().toString();`

Or just share how you're building the `MapboxGeocoding` class?

Comment: I updated my post with three methods I found relevant. I'm still relatively new to using Mapbox so please let me know if you need anything more. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: `chosenLatLng` is null? Is the `address()` section of the _actual_ `CarmenFeature` null/empty? What does the `CarmenFeature` JSON of `results.get(0);` actually look like?

The geocoding call happens on a separate thread, so I would set the intent and finish the `SetEventLocationActivity` inside of the `MapboxGeocoding`'s `onResponse`, rather than calling it after `makeGeocodeSearch(chosenLatLng);` inside of the `set_location_button` onClick listener. The reason why is because the activity could be finishing before the geocode call finishes and before `chosenLocationString` is actually

Comment: set to an address value. Also, here's how I would refactor your `onActivityResult()` code: https://gist.github.com/langsmith/055fae14101df1c10a0a2c54fe866821

Comment: `chosenLatLng` has the correct value, but `results.get(0)`, or `address()`, is null. [Here is the entire value of feature.](http://snippi.com/s/um89fjz)

Your explanation for relocating the intent makes a lot of sense. However, I tried that to no avail. I updated my post with my attempt. How can I make the intent wait until the geocode call finishes?

Comment: @Eric, did you figure this out or do you still need some assistance?

Comment: I'm actually still stuck on it unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/mapbox-java/libjava-services/3.0.1/com/mapbox/api/geocoding/v5/models/CarmenFeature.html#address--)

> A string of the house number for the returned **address** feature

It doesn't seem to work for **Place** feature, so I used this workaround:

`String address = carmenFeature.placeName().replaceFirst(carmenFeature.text().concat(", "),"");`